# ¿Por qué Python no acepta cero a la izquierda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables, estructuras-de-datos

Mi problema es que no puedo usar cero a la izquierda en variables u otros medios de captura de datos como los PyQt5.QLineEdit.text().
De ninguna forma, ni siquiera transformando los dígitos en cadenas de caracteres.

```py
VariableUno = str(01)
VariableDos    = 02
print (VariableUno,VariableDos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python 3.x la razón es histórica más que nada, los ceros iniciales en un número decimal distinto de cero no están permitidos para evitar confusiones permitiendo la desambiguación con literales octales de estilo lenguaje C que se usaba antes de Python 3.

- Para definir un literal `int` en octal antes de Python 3, la sintaxis era:

  > "0" octdigit+

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  diecisiete_octal = 021
  ```
- En Python >= 3.x en cambio la sintaxis es:

  > "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  diecisiete_octal = 0o21
  diecisiete_octal = 0O21
  ```

Por lo tanto, no puedes definir literales con ceros a la izquierda a no ser que sea un 0. La principal motivación para ese cambio de sintaxis de `0` a `0o/0O` se explica en el PEP que la desarrolló en su día:

- [PEP 3127 -- Integer Literal Support and Syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/)

> The default octal representation of integers is silently confusing to people unfamiliar with C-like languages. It is extremely easy to inadvertently create an integer object with the wrong value, because '013' means 'decimal 11', not 'decimal 13', to the Python language itself, which is not the meaning that most humans would assign to this literal.

Que traducido libremente sería algo así:

> La representación octal predeterminada de los enteros es implícitamente  confusa para las personas que no están familiarizadas con los lenguajes tipo C. Es extremadamente fácil crear inadvertidamente un objeto entero con el valor incorrecto, porque '013' significa 'decimal 11', no 'decimal 13', para el lenguaje Python en sí mismo, que no es el significado que la mayoría de las personas asignaría a este literal.

Si necesitas representar un entero con ceros a la izquierda (típico en las fechas por ejemplo) basta con convertirlo en cadena y formatearla adecuadamente:

```
mes = 2
mes_str = "{:02d}".format(mes)
print(mes_str)
```

O si usas Python>= 3.6 puedes usar también literales de cadena formateados:

```
mes = 2
mes_str = f"{mes:02d}"
print(mes_str)
```

Con `02d` indicas que quieres que el entero tenga siempre dos dígitos, en caso de tener menos se debe completar con ceros a la izquierda. Para más información ver:

- [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Si capturas los datos desde teclado vía `input()` o algún widget que retorne una cadena de texto, puedes convertirlo a `int` sin problemas:

```
>>> int("02")
2
```